# sed with placement pattern stops working when assigning to variable

Tags: bash, shell, unix, sed

I have been using `sed` as part of text processing and cleaning up. One of the text changes requires me to replace square brackets with a number inside with just the number (no spaces). Here is an example:

`a[1]` would become `a1`.

(I can't simply get rid of all the square brackets because some of them are needed. Because of this restriction I had to resort to replacement patterns. If there is another `sed` (or other) expression that does the same job without replacement patterns then I would be grateful to see it, yet I am still mainly curious about the nature of my bug).

This is the command I used:

`sed 's/\[\([^] ]*\)\]/\1/g' file.txt`

where file.txt could contain:

`[ [ a[1](t)  +  b[1](t) ] + [ a[2](t) * b[2](t) ] ]`

the command would produce

`[ [ a1(t)  +  b1(t) ] + [ a2(t) * b2(t) ] ]`

Now I try to automate this by putting this in a script. Since I need to manipulate the text in many additional ways, I then create a temporary variable to hold the square bracket change. Here is 'the' script:

```
#!/bin/bash
#$1 is file name.
square_change=$(sed 's/\[\([^] ]*\)\]/\1/g' "$1")
echo $square_change
```

`./script.sh file.txt` outputs:

`[ [ a1(t) + b1(t) ] + [ a2(t) file2.txt file.txt script.sh b2(t) ] ]`
 where `file2.txt file.txt script.sh` are files within my script directory.

I want it to output what `sed 's/\[\([^] ]*\)\]/\1/g' file.txt` originally did. I've spent a bit of time trying different things, but nothing seems to work. Any ideas as to where I went wrong?

Cheers,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the most annoying (yet flexible) things in Unix shell scripting is quoting. The correct version of your script is the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
#$1 is file name.
square_change="$(sed 's/\[\([^] ]*\)\]/\1/g' "$1")"
echo "$square_change"
```

In your case, `echo $square_change` reads as `echo ... * ...`, so `*` gets substituted by the list of files in the current directory. (The quotes around `$()` are not strictly necessary but contribute to the necessary "habit of quoting".)

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to replace numbers between `[...]` then you can use:

```
s='[ [ a[1](t)  +  b[1](t) ] + [ a[2](t) * b[2](t) ] ]'
sed -E 's/\[([0-9]+)\]/\1/g' <<< "$s"

[ [ a1(t)  +  b1(t) ] + [ a2(t) * b2(t) ] ]
```